# How to delete all items of a TFlowLayout at runtime?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio, flowlayout

I want to clear a FlowLayout at run time, is there a function to do that ?
I thought about mapping all its items and free theme, but I don't know how to access its items, any code example please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Children` and `ChildrenCount` properties you can free the items, either in reverse order

```
for i := FlowLayout1.ChildrenCount-1 downto 0 do
  FlowLayout1.Children[i].Free;
```

or in forward order (repeatedly addressing item with index 0)

```
for i := 0 to FlowLayout1.ChildrenCount-1 do
  FlowLayout1.Children[0].Free;
```